# Fast to Speed of Three Nand Architecture, Need Help?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, delay

The following transistor architectures shows **three** implementation of two-input Dynamic NAND.

> Figures a-b-c shows these architectures from fast to slow (speed).

[image]

---

I think this example is wrong and b-a-c is correct. anyone can help me why the example mentioned the speed of these structure in another way?

Comment: And what is _"a-b-c is sort this architecture from fast to slow"_ supposed to mean?

Comment: figure (a), figure(b) and figure (c), means figure a is faster from others, then (b) and (a) is slower @pipe

Comment: So now you completely changed the quote. Are you quoting this from a changing book?

Comment: Also, why is it related to Arduino?

Comment: This is typo I correct it sorry, @pipe

Comment: I'm glad you correct the mistakes so quickly, hopefully someone can help you with this question. It's beginning to look clearer.

Comment: @pipe is it clear now?

Comment: I think so. I can't answer the question though, I don't know enough about this subject.

Comment: Are you sure you're not reading these the wrong way? To me it looks like the are ordered `b`, `a` and `c`.

Comment: I think like as you "B-A- and C" but the Note example says "A-B-C" !! @pipe

Answer (score 1):

The question does not specify clock and clockbar.  Are we are to assume that clockbar is generated after clock? But, in real digital circuits clocks are implemented using a tree.  This means you can either go UP or DOWN the tree from a spot, either is an inversion.  So, clockbar may well be before clock.

**But, I will assume both clock and clockbar are arriving at the same time and opposite polarity.**

The question does not specify the relative ratio between PMOS and NMOS.  **I'll just assume they are even.**

Both A & B have a similar topology, except A uses an NMOS to charge the internal node during the low-phase of the clock, and B uses a PMOS to pull up the internal node during the low-phase of clock.  Precharging internal nodes in dynamic gates is done to mitigate problems due to charge sharing.  The downsides are increased area and power.

In A, the internal node is precharged to the supply voltage, because a PMOS can pull up fully to a high value.
In B, the internal node is precharged to the supply voltage minus a threshold voltage, because the NMOS cannot fully pull up to a high value.

**So, by this logic, B is faster than A**, because when switching A has extra charge to discharge during a falling edge.

**C which is always slower because there is more contention created by the dual-keeper structure.**  What I mean by this, is both keepers are fighting to keep the output node and the internal node in pulldown stack at '1' when the output is a '1'.

So, if you want to write a '0' into this circuit after precharge (only time dynamic NAND's will really have a 'delay', since precharge causing output-rise doesn't quite count), you have to fight both PMOS which are currently trying to pull the output node/internal node up to '1'.

***One guess for why they have A faster than B?*** The clockbar signal.  If clockbar is assumed to be generated from clock, then there will be a gate delay (there are other ways to generate opposite polarity signals w/ minimal phase shift).  This means that when clock rises, and the inputs try to pull down the output node in circuit B, there is (for a brief period = inverter delay) an NMOS trying to pull the internal node up.  This is contention and will slow down the circuit.

Comment: Whit this example, without any specific other condition you agree with a-b-c or b-a-c?

Comment: If the clock and clockbar have no delay, then B-A-C due to less to discharge.  If there is some positive delay from clock(rise)->clockbar(fall), then there will be contention in this time from the NMOS attempting to pull up the output node, and so it could be A-B-C (although the first condition still applies)